# Error con if ilogico en c++

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente código

```
int m_fila_seleccionada = -1;
if(m_fila_seleccionada >= m_filas.size())
    m_fila_seleccionada = 0;
else if(m_fila_seleccionada < 0)
    m_fila_seleccionada = m_filas.size() - 1;
```

`m_filas` es un `std::vector<Elemento*>` que contiene 9 elementos, el problema es que entra en el `if` NO en el `else if`, he imprimido los valores dentro y muestra que `m_filas.size()` es igual a 9 y `m_fila_seleccion = -1`, pero de todas formas entro.
si hago lo siguiente:

```
if(m_fila_seleccionada >= m_filas.size())
{
    int valor = m_filas.size();
    if(m_fila_seleccionada >= valor)
         std::cout << "Es mayor\n";
    else
         std::cout << "Es menor\n";
}
```

Me imprime "Es menor", ¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?, he buscado errores con punteros pero nada. (Es mucho el código como para ponerlo completo) ¿Como puedo buscar el error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema probablemente se deba a que `vector::size` devuelve un tipo de dato **unsigned int** ([ver documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/)) y lo estas comparando con un `int`, el cual posiblemente en tu compilador haga algún tipo de manejo impredecible (e indeseado)

En mi compilador este código da un Warning y no compila:

```
std::vector<int> m_filas = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int var=0;

if(m_filas.size() > var) { // <~~~~ WARNING
    std::cout << "Es mayor";
}
```

> Warning, comparison of integer of diferent signedness
> 'std::vector::size_type' {aka 'unsigned int'} and 'int'

Al asignar el `unsigned` a una variable `int` digamos que "corrige" el problema, ya que el compilador hace la conversión de tipos.

```
int valor = m_filas.size();
if(valor > var) { // <-- Compila y funciona correctamente
.
.
.
```

Comment: No pensé que size() retornara un unsigned int, mi compilador no mostró ninguna advertencia, se me había olvidado agregarlas en la opción de compilación. Ahora tengo mucho que corregir. Gracias.

Comment: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<long long int>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Werror=sign-compare], ¿no deberia ser un long unsigned int?, al compilador no le importa si es unsigned int o long unsigned int, ¿cual es mejor?, leí que usar long puede causar problemas.